# Intel HD Graphics - how to create a keyboard shortcut to switch profiles?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intel-graphics

I have defined 2 different profiles in Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel.

I would like to be able to switch between those profiles with an icon shortcut or keyboard shortcut.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: AutoIT or AutoHotkey?

Comment: You can try asking if such a third party app exist at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread and despite solutions didn't work, they allowed me to find one and write a batch script (.bat) to execute profile change.
Here is a step-by-step tutorial for everybody:

1. Open Intel HD Graphics Control Panel and go to Task manager.
2. In processes right click Intel Panel and go to details. There go to file location of the process. (for me it's `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_dd5d08598ac3d75d`)
3. Now all you need is to create bat with

`C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_dd5d08598ac3d75d\GfxUIEx.exe -profile profilename`

Profile name cannot include spaces, didn't test with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I did a fair bit of research on this when running BootCamp on my mid-2011 MacBook Air. Unfortunately as far as I know, the integrated Intel graphics control panel doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, with profiles set up in Intel HD Graphics Control Panel, you can switch between them using command line

```
C:\Windows\System32\GfxUIEx.exe -profile <profile name>
```

(`-profile` switch is case-sensitive, profile name isn't)

You can put that in a .bat file, and create a shortcut to the bat file on your desktop, then assign a shortcut key to that shortcut in Properties.